# Firebase: Wait For Multiple Queries To Finish

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have multiple references to different Firebase database locations, that all fetch some data. I need to have all data collected before continuing with the next step of processing that data. The code is as follows:

```
for ref in baseRefs {
     ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "datetime").queryLimited(toFirst: 4).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (postRefs) in
          for postRef in postRefs.children {
               let snapshotValue = ((postRef as! DataSnapshot).value) as! [String: AnyObject]
               let dummyPost = Post(key: (postRef as! DataSnapshot).key, dummyTextCount: snapshotValue["textcount"] as! Int, datetime: snapshotValue["datetime"] as! Int)
               self.postsHeap.enqueue(dummyPost)
          }
     })
}
```

I want the heap to contain all posts fetched from these queries before displaying them in a table view (because of the timestamp-sorting). Is there a way to wait for multiple queries like above to finish before continuing?

**Edit:** As I need to fetch data from different nodes from Firebase I can't just make it a single query call.

Comment: From the code you posted, you only have one Firebase call, and it's unclear where the sorting is being done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know how many refs there are, and you only want to sort and update the UI when the last ref is processed, how about a simple ..if.. statement to see if the last ref has been returned. Something like this:

```
let lastRefIndex = baseRefs.count - 1 //the index of the last ref
for (index, ref) in baseRefs.enumerated { //index tracks which ref we are on
     ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "datetime").queryLimited(toFirst: 4)
        .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (postRefs) in
          for postRef in postRefs.children {
               let snapshotValue = ...
               let dummyPost = ...
               self.postsHeap.enqueue(dummyPost)
          }

          //the following code will execute once for each ref as the data becomes
          //  valid. So index will only equal the lastRefIndex when all of the
          //  data has been returned.
          if index == lastRefIndex { 
             self.postsHeap.sort()
             updateUI
          }
     })
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could utilize `DispatchGroup` to wait the other queries to be finished.

*Trimmed your code a bit:*

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated)

dispatchQueue.async(group: group,
                      qos: .userInitiated,
                    flags: DispatchWorkItemFlags.assignCurrentContext,
                  execute: {
    for ref in baseRefs {
        group.enter() // Enter the group for each reference.

        ref.queryOrdered... with: { (postRefs) in {
            ....
            self.postsHeap.enqueue(dummyPost)

            group.leave() // Leave the group after finishing.
        }
    }
}

group.notify(queue: .main) {                
    // Every ref has finished, continue from here.
}
```

Comment: I use this in my code, but I always use `DispatchQueue.main.async{...}`. What's the advantage of using what you wrote?

Comment: @Tometoyou In which part are you using that? To speak for the whole code; it can dispatch calls in parallel, and defining the `qos` as `.userInitiated` gives high priority to these calls (I'm also using `.userInteractive`) while not hogging the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to achieve this but it's bad practice with Firebase to structure your data in a way that requires multiple observers at different DB locations to get data required for one purpose.

You mention posts so I assume you're creating a feed of some kind.

So instead of getting all the posts from different parts of your database and combining/sorting them on the client, each user will have a feeds node and when a post is saved you also save the id of that post in the users feed node then your query is just one observer at the user's feed node which already has everything you need.

Also I can see your sorting by 'datetime', did you know in Firebase ids are sorted by time so you can sort by other children if required then orderByKey and limit to last 4 and then you can fetch the most recent 4 posts while also querying other children.

You can use multi-path updates or cloud functions to duplicate (denormalise) your data across your database. If your coming from SQL this can feel quite weird but its normal with Firebase.

[Here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html) is a firebase blog with more info on the right structure and denormalising your data.